# Flatten javascript multi dimentional nested array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to flatten an array but I'm having difficulties.

**My code:**

```js
    var arr = [["2"],["3", "4"], "5", [["6"], ["7"]] ];
    
    var res = [].concat.apply([], arr);
    
    //Using reduce(ES5)

   function test(args){
     var sum = args.reduce(function(acc, val){
       acc.concat(Array.isArray(val)? test(val): val);
     });
    }

    //Regular implementation
    function test2(arr){
      var result = [];
      arr.forEach(function(val){
        if(Array.isArray(val)){
          result = [].concat.apply([], val);
        } else {
          result.concat(val);
        }
      });
      return result;
    }
    
    console.log(test(arr));
    console.log(test2(arr));
```

Expected Output:

```
["2", "3", "4","5", "6", "7"]
```

Can someone enlighten me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: [Check out this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @Jhecht i did try that intitally, but it was written in ES6. I have added my ES5 version but am not sure what am i doing wrong over there. It's giving me undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @Andreas Not sure if this is exact duplicate as OP is referring to nested structure. `[[[]], [[]]]` and not `[[],[],[]]`

Comment: @Rajesh http://stackoverflow.com/a/15030117/402037 -> `flatten([[[1, [1.1]], 2, 3], [4, 5]]); // [1, 1.1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: @Andreas Yes this answer is made to serve nested structure but as of question, still not sure if its a dupe and will hold my answer and vote.

Comment: Your `test` function is not returning anything; you need to add `return sum;` to the end of it.

Answer (score 5):

Thats it. So simple

```js
var arr = [["2"], ["3", "4"], "5", [["6"], ["7"]]];

function test2(arr) {
    return arr.toString().split(",");
}

console.log(test2(arr));
```

Comment: ahh, clever approach, should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Only works with arrays of strings without commas. Does not work for `[{foo: 1}, [{age: 2}, {foo: 3}]]` or `['a string, has commas']`

Comment: i answered for OP's question. There are different scenarios. As JavaScript runs on browser, each line of code is more important to keep efficiency. In this scenario, this line is most efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Since its a nested structure, you should use `recursion`

#### Logic

- Loop over passed array and check if current item is an array.
- If yes, repeat the process.
- If not, push value to temp array.
- Merge return value of each recursion to previous one.

#### Array.forEach

```js
var arr = [["2"],["3", "4"], "5", [["6"], ["7"]] ];

function getFlattenArray(array){
  var _tmp = [];
  array.forEach(function(item){
    if(Array.isArray(item)) {
      _tmp = _tmp.concat(getFlattenArray(item))
    }
    else{
      _tmp.push(item);
    }
  })
  return _tmp;
}

var result = getFlattenArray(arr);

console.log(result)
```

#### Array.reduce

```js
var arr = [["2"],["3", "4"], "5", [["6"], ["7"]] ];

function getFlattenArray(array){
  return array.reduce(function(p,c){
    if(Array.isArray(c)) {
      p = p.concat(getFlattenArray(c))
    }
    else{
      p.push(c);
    }
    return p
  }, [])
}

var result = getFlattenArray(arr);

console.log(result)
```

---

**ES6 Version**

```js
var arr = [["2"],["3", "4"], "5", [["6"], ["7"]] ];

function getFlattenArray(array){
  return array.reduce((p,c) => (Array.isArray(c) ? p=p.concat(getFlattenArray(c)) : p.push(c) ) && p, [])
}

var result = getFlattenArray(arr);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: damn.. thanks so much. This was helpful! .. Can you also give me a solution with Array.reduce?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason the code I linked you wasn't working was that you probably made the same error I did. I believe (don't really care to look it up, someone will correct me if I am wrong) that arrow functions automatically return the last line, so when turning the code into ES5 you forget to return the `arr.reduce(...)`.

This works for me, Chrome on Windows.

```js
var arr = [
  ["2"],
  ["3", "4"], "5", [
    ["6"],
    ["7"]
  ]
];

function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    return acc.concat(Array.isArray(val) ? flatten(val) : val);
  }, []);
}

console.log(flatten(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [["2"],["3", "4"], "5", [["6"], ["7"]] ];

var flatten = arr.flat(Infinity);

console.log(flatten);
```

Since [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) has been included in the standard ECMAScript 2019 (ES10), there is no need to implement your own methods to flatten arrays.

The `flat` method can take a parameter to specify how deep a nested array structure should be flattened. In the above example I'm passing the global scope variable `Infinity` so it flattens all the levels.

At the time of writing (04/11/2019) all major browsers except Edge have implemented the feature in their newer versions. Babel 7.4.0 (with core-js@3) also comes with it.